# How to animate circular progress in Apple WatchKit?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch

I have 50 circular images (progress-1.png, progress-2.png, etc) that represent the progress of a circle. If I come up with a percentage value, how can I animate the background image of a group to show the progress of that percentage value?

Comment: This GitHub project may be helpful: `A progress view to be used within Apple Watch projects` (https://github.com/e-sites/ESArcProgressView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
// Using a fixed percentage for this example
CGFloat percentage = 0.5f;
NSUInteger totalImages = 50;
NSUInteger imageCount = (totalImages * percentage);

[self.interfaceImage setImageNamed:@"progress-"];
[self.interfaceImage startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, imageCount)
                                            duration:1.0
                                         repeatCount:1];
```